# IMAP to Exchange 2013 migration: powershell cmdlets don't recognize -IMAP

Tags: exchange-2013

I've set up an Exchange 2013 where email is being migrated to. When trying to run the necessary cmdlets to start a migration, the -IMAP switch is not recognized. An example:

```
[PS] C:\users\Administrator\Documents>New-MigrationEndpoint -IMAP -Name OldServer -RemoteServer imap.example.net
A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IMAP'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-MigrationEndpoint], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,New-MigrationEndpoint
    + PSComputerName        : exchange1.example.local

[PS] C:\users\Administrator\Documents>
```

According to the docs, this is valid syntax: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj218611(v=exchg.150).aspx

But wherever I need to use -IMAP, the error message as above returns. Do I need some extra piece of software that isn't installed by default by Exchange 2013?

Thanks,

Comment: are you trying to migrate FROM an imap server to Exchange 2013 on-premise?  I could be completely wrong here, but I thought that the IMAP migrationendpoint was to allow you to go from Exchange to Exchange Online (Office 365) using an IMAP connection as the endpoint.  I didn't think this was for migrations FROM an IMAP server.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to migrate FROM an IMAP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an IMAP endpoint only works if you are migrating to Office 365. You can not use an IMAP endpoint to migrate to an on-prem Exchange server.

I've never tried this but you could subscribe to Office 365 and migrate the mailboxes there, then use the Exchange mailbox move tool to bring the mailboxes on-prem.

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me nuts because even using get-help etc... showed examples with -IMAP. Nice to know they didn't bother mentioning it only works for Office 365 >:(

Comment: In teh documentation you linked to under "Detailed Information", it says for "IMAP migration" that it is for Office 365. I agree it could be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong tool for the job (migrating FROM an IMAP server to on-premise Exchange).  Exchange 2007 used to have a tool that did this (The transport suite I believe it was called), but it went away in 2010.

You'll either have to get a 3rd party tool if you want to do this in bulk or as a seamless migration (check with Quest, MigrationWiz, and others).  Or you'll need to connect Outlook to both the new Exchange mailbox and the old IMAP mailbox and manually drag/drop the mail over into Exchange for each user.  (or export the whole thing to a PST and re-import the PST)